# Java equivalent of Objective C method scoped static variables

Tags: java, objective-c

I'm porting some Objective C code to Java.  One of the C methods looks like this:

```
void method(){

static int variable;

...

}
```

My understanding of this is that variable has a lifetime equal to the execution life of the containing compilation unit but visible only to the method.  AFAIK, there is no equivalent for this in Java so I am considering using class level static variables to do the job.  I understand the risk of widening the visibility of the variables and the resultant decrease in maintainability but if I carefully check all of the other methods of the class for clashes, I can handle that with judicious commenting.

Am I missing anything?  Any other risks I should consider?

Thanks to all for your contributions to SO.

Cheers

Simon

Comment: Apart from visibility one more thing to worry would be threading. If multi-threading, same variable would be updated by multiple threads.

Comment: [`static` local variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)

Comment: Thanks veer. I fully understand what static means.  My question relates to the correct design choice for implementing method level static fields in non-static methods - which, to my knowledge, have no direct equivalent in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing anything? Any other risks I should consider?

You should really consider what state is logically part of. Is it actually part of the state of an *instance* of the containing class? If so, make it an instance variable. Is it logically state of the type itself? If so, a static variable is reasonable - but statics are often the enemy of testability, threading etc.

Is it actually logically part of state of a *different* class? Possibly a new one which doesn't exist yet? You might want to have a static final reference to an instance of that new class, for example.

Basically, let the natural location of the state inform the location of the variable.

Comment: Is it actually logically part of state of a different class? Possibly a new one which doesn't exist yet?  Actually, I think that's the correct answer but, the method itself contains enormously complex math which I frankly don't understand and should start with a "here be dragons" comment.  The variables themselves are named k,v, vu, dblvu, vv and i.  Gives you some idea of what I'm facing! My saviour is that I also have pre-proved unit tests for the method so I will know if my implemenation works.  I think I'll try creating a new class.  Thanks for the wisdom.